# Error: Mapping should be created with `aes() or `aes_()`

Tags: r

```
df %>%
 group_by(state_name) %>%
 summarise(TotalPopulation = mean(population_total)) %>%
 ggplot(data=df, aes(x= state_name, y=TotalPopulation)) +
 geom_bar("stat=identity")
```

I am getting the error

> Error: Mapping should be created with `aes() or`aes_()`.

Comment: Only 'identity' should be in quotes in geom_bar.

Answer (score 1):

2 issues, you dont need the `data` argument as it is already piped in. And as @rpolicastro says only 'identity' should be in quotes:

```
df %>%
 group_by(state_name) %>%
 summarise(TotalPopulation = mean(population_total)) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x= state_name, y=TotalPopulation)) +
 geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's re-create problem with `mtcars`

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(TotalMpg = mean(mpg)) %>%
  ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x= cyl, y=TotalMpg)) +
  geom_bar("stat=identity") 
Error: Mapping should be created with `aes() or `aes_()`
```

There 2 point to fix:

- you pass your data with pipe, so `data=mtcars` should be removed
- quotes should be `geom_bar(stat="identity")` instead of `geom_bar("stat=identity")`

Following code produces plot

```
mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    summarise(TotalMpg = mean(mpg)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x= cyl, y=TotalMpg)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
```